# Repair links between moved files in Mercurial

Tags: java, svn, git, mercurial

Over the course of having this repo (originally SVN) I've not been to good with keeping file links together. I've changed IDE's twice, split the project into Netbeans modules, and mavenized the project over its time. Most of the file history is lost, mainly because during mavenizing I deleted the entire trunk, committed, copied over the maven project, and committed. Not exactly the best idea, as I later found out all history reset to that point. Its gotten so bad that a repository stats program is useless since it says I have 50,000 lines of code invested instead of ~8,000.

Is there any way to fix all the broken file histories? I have access to SVN and Git if Mercurial can't do it

Answer (score 3):

Hrm, and the time you did your delete and copy you'd've been fine had you just done `hg addremove --similarity 90` which says "remove everything that's gone, add everything that's new, and if they're 90% similar to one another count is as a rename".

Now that that opportunity has passed there's no way to move one w/o re-writing your repository, which invalidates all the clones out there in the wild as all the node ids (hashes) change.   If that's okay and you have a largely linear history you can probably get by with something like this:

```
hg export --output "../patch-%n.patch" 0:tip  # exports every changeset to a patch file
cd ..
hg init newrepo
cd newrepo
hg import --similarity 90 ../patch*
```

That takes a linear history from your first commit to your last (excluding branches and other heads, etc.) exports them to patches, creates a new empty repo, and imports the changesets using the rename detection feature.

This is a pretty drastic act so make sure it's really worth it to you and keep your old repo around for good measure.

Comment: As I'm the only person on this repo and nobody has cloned it, I should be fine messing with it. However, is there a way to merge the delete and copy commits I did while in SVN? Because you still have the problem of broken history before the mavenizing. The only way I can think of is to roll back to that specific revision, do the work, then apply all the changes on top. But that's something I'm not so familiar on how to do in Mercurial and I think it would loose all the timestamps, something I want to preserver.

Comment: If you're going the export-everything import-everything route you can merge two changesets by using `hg import --no-commit` and then doing both imports before doing a `hg commit`.  Timestamps can be set to anything you want on a changeset (see `commit --date`) and filetimestamps aren't tracked at all.

Comment: Going back to this question, I was trying to do this but am running into issues recreating the repo. I export with `hg export --git -a -o "../patch-%r.patch" -vv 0:tip` and import with (greatly simplified) `for i in \`ls .. | grep patch\`; do hg import --similarity 90 --user "..." --force --date "..." ../$i; done;`. However I get lots of import errors: Files don't exist, they already exist, or get rejected. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TheLQ Any non-linearities in your history will need to be handled specially.  You'll need to 'hg update' to the parent of each changeset before you import it.  When two changesets in order or parent-child you can skip the 'hg update' since your last commit left you updated to the parent of the next repo, but every time that's not the case you'll need to do it manually.  This was the "largely linear" warning I was giving you.  Also globs work in for loops so you can do: `for i in ../*patch* ; do`

Comment: This was originally a SVN repo that only had code in the `trunk`.  And when I converted it to mercurial with `hg convert` I never did any kind of branching, multiple heads, or other weirdness like that. So I'm confused on how I could get errors like this

Comment: Hrm, when you do `hg log -G` on the post-convert repo (may require enabling the graphlog extension) does the history look entirely linear?  Perhaps change the `hg import` to include `--no-commit` and add a 'hg commit --addremove' at the end of each iteration in the loop?

Comment: @Ry4an Checked, in TourtiseHg I see no other branches, heads, or anything else that would cause problems; its just one linear line. However, even with `hg commit --addremove` I'm still getting rejected patches due to files already existing, which is strange since you can't commit a file that already exists. Next comment has loop I'm using

Comment: Command (greatly simplified) `for i in ../*patch* ; do hg import --force --no-commit --similarity 90 --user "..." --date "..." $i; hg commit --addremove -m "..."; done;`